# Mathematical matrices implementation

Tags: c++, matrix

As a Java programmer who's trying his hand at C++, I thought I'd start building a library for working with matrices as my first C++ project. I've got very little C++ experience and it's been a long time since I've even so much as dabbled in it.

So far I've only implemented an addition function, but I think this should be enough code to establish my current coding style.

I was wondering if anyone would be able to give my code a look over and see if it conforms to standards and if there are any cleaner ways of doing anything.

Here is my matrix.h file:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Matrix {

    private:
        int** array;

    public:
        int m, n;
        Matrix(int m, int n);

        static Matrix* add(Matrix* m1, Matrix* m2);
        int get(int i, int j);
        void set (int i, int j, int e);

        ~Matrix();

};

#endif
```

and my matrix.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

Matrix::Matrix(int var_m, int var_n) {
    m = var_m;
    n = var_n;
    array = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        array[i] = new int[m];
    cout << "foo" << endl;
    cout << m << " " << n << endl;
}

Matrix* Matrix::add(Matrix* m1, Matrix* m2) {

    if (m1->m != m2->m or m1->n != m2->n) {
        cerr << "Error: Mismatched sizes in Matrix.add()" << endl;
        throw;
    }

    Matrix* res = new Matrix(m1->m, m1->n);

    for (int i = 0; i < res->m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < res->n; j++) {
            res->array[i][j] = m1->array[i][j] + m2->array[i][j];
        }
    }

    return res;
}

int Matrix::get(int i, int j) {
    return array[i][j];
}

void Matrix::set(int i, int j, int e) {
    array[i][j] = e;
}

Matrix::~Matrix() {
    delete array;
}
```

and just some test code thrown together in my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // --- Test code ---
    int m, n;
    Matrix* mat1;
    Matrix* mat2;
    Matrix* mat3;

    cout << "m: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "n: ";
    cin >> n;

    mat1 = new Matrix(m, n);
    mat2 = new Matrix(m, n);

    mat1->set(0,2,5);

    mat3 = Matrix::add(mat1, mat2);

    for (int i = 0; i < mat3->m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat3->n; j++) {
            cout << mat3->get(i,j);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    delete mat1, mat2, mat3;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. There is a bug in your `Matrix` destructor. `delete array` is not correct. It was allocated using an array form of the `new` operator, so it must be deleted using an array form of `delete`(that is, `delete[]`). The current version of your code invokes undefined behavior. But simply changing it to `delete[] array` is not enough to fix it. There is still a memory leak here. A correct version of the destructor should look this way:

   ```
   ~Matrix() {
       for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
           delete[] array[row];
       delete[] array;
   }
   ```

   It is necessary because deleting an array of pointers does not delete the objects pointed by this pointers.
2. It looks like the size of the `array` is not correct, either. You allocate an array of pointers of size `n`, but then you use it as if it had a size `m`.

   ```
   array = new int*[n];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       array[i] = new int[m];
   ...
   for (int i = 0; i < res->m; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < res->n; j++) {
           res->array[i][j] = m1->array[i][j] + m2->array[i][j];
       }
   }
   ```

   This code invokes undefined behavior in case `n != m`.
3. You should probably implement a copy constructor and a copy-assignment operator. A default copy constrcutor(and assignment operator) just copies the pointer, not the content of the `Matrix`(I'm not sure if you it is what you want).
4. A good way to get rid of many bugs in your code is to use standard containers instead of dynamic memory allocation with raw pointers. For example, you can use a `std::vector` to store the elements of the `Matrix`:

   ```
    class Matrix {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> array;
        ...
    };
   ```

   It allows you to avoid manual memory management issues.
5. Using raw pointers and the `new` operator is not common in modern C++ in general.
6. C++ has operator overloading, and it is usually used in C++ programs. For example, matrix addition is a good candidate for overloading the `+` operator.

   ```
   class Matrix {
       ...
   public:
       Matrix operator+(const Matrix& rhs) const {
           // Check the validity of input parameters.
           Matrix res(n, m);
           // Addition goes here.
           return res;
       }

       ...
   };
   ```

   This example also shows a conventional way to pass arguments without copying them: by const reference(passing a pointer to them is not common in modern C++).
7. Member-functions that do not change the instance should have a `const` qualifier.
8. It is a good practice to write unit tests instead of ad-hoc testing(it is not C++ specific, of course).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @kraskevich answer:

It is better to use linear array of size m*n and compute offsets when needed (offset = i + m*j). In this case you can use algorithms and iterators, i.e. add two matrices would be:

```
class Matrix {
    ...
    std::vector<int> arr;
    ...
    friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b);
    ...
};
Matrix operator+(const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b) {
    assert(a.m == b.m && a.n == b.n);
    Matrix result;
    result.reserve(a.size());
    std::transform(a.arr.begin(), a.arr.end(), b.arr.begin(), 
               std::back_inserter(result.arr), std::plus<int>());
    return result;
}
```

Also this approach is faster and can be better optimized (you use MADD and memory read instead of two memory reads)

Answer (score 0):

- C++ offers operator overload feature. For element access it is customary to overload an `operator()` (function call):

  ```
  const int& Matrix::operator()(int i, int j) const;
  int& Matrix::operator()(int i, int j);
  ```

  instead of Java-style `get` and `set`, which leads to a somewhat better readability, e.g.

  ```
  m(1, 2) = 1;          // cf m.set(1, 2, 1)
  int x = m(1, 2);      // cf x = m.get(1, 2)
  ```
- Similarly, `operator+()` is preferred to an `add` method.

Answer (score 0):

**Major objection:**

Don't use

```
using namespace std;
```

in a .h file. In brings the entire `std` namespace into the scope of any file that `#include`s the .h file. If you need anything from the `std` namespace, just use them explicitly -- i.e. use `std::vector` instead of `vector`.

**Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` for member variable.**

I agree with @kraskevich that you should change the member variable to

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array;
```

This allows you to overload the array operator, `[]`.

```
std::vector<int>& operator[](size_t index) 
{
   return array[index];
}
```

and the `const` version.

```
std::vector<int> const& operator[](size_t index) const
{
   return array[index];
}
```

Now, you can use the following syntax to access the elements of a matrix:

```
Matrix mat(10, 15);
mat[0][0] = 10;
```

That's more idiomatic than

```
Matrix mat(10, 15);
mat.set(0, 0, 10);
```

You can also use:

```
int x = mat[0][0];
```

instead of

```
int x = mat.get(0, 0);
```

**Remove the member variables `m` and `n`**

With a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` as the member variable, you have access to `m` and `n`. There is no need for storing redundant data.

**Argument types in the constructor**

Since it makes no sense to have negative values of `m` or `n` as inputs to the constructor, I would make then an unsigned integral type.

```
Matrix(unsigned int m, unsigned int n);
```

or

```
Matrix(size_t m, size_t n);
```

**Provide an iterator and functions to return iterators**

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator iterator;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>>::const_iterator const_iterator;

iterator begin() { return array.begin(); }
const_iterator begin() const { return array.begin(); }

iterator end() { return array.end(); }
const_iterator end() const { return array.end(); }
```

Now, you can iterate over the elements of a `Matrix` using the range `for` construct:

```
for ( auto& row : mat )
   for ( auto element : row )
      cout << element;
```